# Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

First I have created an in-memory table with one column and using those column values I have an inner join with another table. While doing so I am getting this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable **@Temporary**.

Can any one explain where I am going wrong?

```
DECLARE @ID INT
Declare @Temporary Table
(
AccountID INT
)  

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR

SELECT DISTINCT ParentItem from ItemBillOfMaterial

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN 

Insert into @Temporary Values(@ID)  

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID;

END

SELECT UOM FROM Item

INNER JOIN @Temporary

ON Item.ItemID=@Temporary.AccountID

CLOSE cur;

DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use an alias when referencing the table in your join condition

```
SELECT UOM FROM Item
INNER JOIN @Temporary t
ON Item.ItemID=t.AccountID
```

Whilst that fixes the problem you're having, you don't need the temporary table, or the cursor. This query could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT UOM 
FROM Item
WHERE ItemID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ParentItem FROM ItemBillOfMaterial)
```

Comment: Can you explain why i have to use alias.Item table does not have  AccountID column. so conflation.

Comment: I'm sure a SQL server guru could provide a better reason why, I've assumed it's just been a simplification of the parser on Microsoft's part.

Comment: Thanks for your help.It is wroking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you need a cursor or a temp table for that, I think this does about the same in one query

```
SELECT UOM FROM Item
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ParentItem AccountID 
  from ItemBillOfMaterial
) Temporary
ON Item.ItemID=Temporary.AccountID
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answers are probably fine, wouldn't it be better doing this:
`SELECT UOM FROM Item WHERE UOM.ItemID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ParentItem FROM ItemBillOfMaterial)`
instead of cursor fetching? Fetch is very slow and based on the code you added above the job doesn't seem too complicated.
Sorry if I'm wrong here and you just simplified the task to focus on the issue you face.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I am learning how to use cursor using that query.