# Why I get "Must declare the scalar variable "@rollnum"" error when I try to insert?

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

my code given is--------

```
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CHROMA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=marksheet;Integrated Security=True"); 
                cn.Open();

                if (cn != null)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter roll number");
                   string rollnum =Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter name");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter gender");
                    string gen = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter DOB");
                    string DOB = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter father name");
                    string father = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter course");
                    string course = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter address");
                    string add = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter city");
                    string city = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter state");
                    string state = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter phone");
                    string phone = Console.ReadLine();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into student (rollno,name,gender,dob,fname,course,address,city,state,phone) values(@rollnum,@name,@gen,@DOB,@father,@course,@add,@city,@state,@phone,)",cn);

                   int row= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if(row >0)

                    Console.WriteLine("Record inserted...");
                    cn.Close();
                    cn.Dispose();
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("please open connection first!!");
```

Comment: Isn't that obvious? You declare your parameters in your `SqlCommand` but you _never_ add them as a parameter. Add all your parameters and their values like `cmd.Parameters.Add("@rollnum", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = rollnum;` But before writing more code, please read a good book about ADO.NET.

Comment: Possible duplicated of [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168565/must-declare-the-scalar-variable) and [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363415/must-declare-the-scalar-variable).

Comment: By the way, why you tagged with `mysql`? If so, why you are using `SqlCommand`?

Answer (score 0):

you should bind your parameters after creating the command and before executing the command.
for example:
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rollnum", rollnum);`
(do the same for all other parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't get full answer, here is mine..

As I said in my comment, you declared your parameter names in your `SqlCommand` but you never add them as a parameter name and their scalar values. That's why your error message says;

> Must declare the scalar variable "@rollnum”

since it's a first parameter you defined in your command. And when you try to execute it, it is *too* normal to expect a scalar variable instead of a parameter name.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` automatically instead of calling `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` methods manually.

And `STATE` can be [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in future SQL Server versions. You *might* need to use it as `[STATE]`.

I assume your columns are `nvarchar` types, here is my example;

```
using(var cn = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = @"insert into student (rollno,name,gender,dob,fname,course,address,city,[state],phone) 
                       values(@rollnum,@name,@gen,@DOB,@father,@course,@add,@city,@state,@phone)";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@rollnum", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = rollnum;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@gen", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = gen;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DOB;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@father", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = father;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@course", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = course;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@add", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = add;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = city;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@state", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = state;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = phone;

   cn.Open();
   if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
      Console.WriteLine("Record inserted...");
}
```